# What is the "<>" operator in an elixir function signature?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I see this function signature sometimes and can't find anything on it:

```
def handle("user:" <> id), do: Repo.get(User, id)
```

I am new to erlang/elixir so I assume this is some sort of pattern matching for `user:1` and `user:2`, but I haven't seen any articles or information about this specifically in the Elixir guides.

What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, it's a pattern in this case. `"user:" <> id` will match any binary starting with `user:`, and assign the part of the string after `user:` to `id`.

```
iex(1)> "user:" <> id = "user:"
"user:"
iex(2)> id
""
iex(3)> "user:" <> id = "user:123"
"user:123"
iex(4)> id
"123"
iex(5)> "user:" <> id = "user"
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: "user"
```

Note that the same operator is also used to concatenate binaries when used as an expression:

```
iex(1)> id = "123"
"123"
iex(2)> "user:" <> id
"user:123"
```